# Sizing logo for Outlook desktop

Tags: html, css, outlook, image-size

[image]I am building emails using a Drag & Drop editor in a CRM (Dynamics 365 w/ ClickDimensions). For the logo, I am using HTML to insert an image. The logo shows up fine for every email client except Outlook desktop. Here it shows up full-sized and ignores the inline styling. If I add "width= ... " inline with the img, it shows up smaller, but it's oriented in the top left of the email instead of where it's supposed to be.

I found the following conditional and tried to make it work, but it's not doing anything.

```
<div style="box-sizing: border-box; white-space: normal;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:1.42857143; word-wrap: break-word !important; white-space: normal;  padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <style>
            #logo {
                max-width: 130px !important;
                padding-left: 40px !important;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <a href="https://www.southuniversity.edu/"><img id="logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dceh-marketing/SU/Logos/Systemwide/PNGs/South_Estab1899_CMYK.png" alt="South University Logo" style="max-width:130px; display:block; margin:auto;"></a>
</div>
```

I cannot write any code outside of the  that is given in the box, this is not a full-fledged html editor. Anything outside gets erased. Any ideas on what I can write to make the logo appear properly in Outlook? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't write code beyond that box, you're going to have to live with the logo being the incorrect size in Outlook.

Outlook is problematic when it comes to images. It will display images at the size they were created and ignore your inline style width declaration. The fix is to add `width="130"` to the `<img>`.

An example:

```
<img id="logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dceh-marketing/SU/Logos/Systemwide/PNGs/South_Estab1899_CMYK.png" width="130" alt="South University Logo" style="max-width:130px; display:block; margin:auto;">
```

The image size is actually 344x161 and I am guessing Outlook is displaying it at that size. Either resize the image or add `width="160"` to the `<img>` or live with the issue.

Good luck.